# angularjs get DOM ng-model

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom

Every `input/element` In Angularjs will bind a `ng-model`

without using `Id` and `Class` to get the element `DOM`

We can use

`$('[ng-model="Model"]')`

But If the model is under `ng-repeat`,

How can I get the DOM without using the unique `DOM`

Example:

`<input type="text" ng-model="name"/>`

`$('[ng-model="name"]')`
to get the DOM

what if I want to get all the input DOM (ng-repeat)

```
<div ng-repeat="name in names">
    <input type="text" ng-model="name"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to decorate your elements with ID or css classes I don't think you have much choice to get those DOM elements. One option could be-

```
$('[ng-repeat="name in names"] :input').length
```

Comment: Thanks for your option. But I won't know it's ng-repeat type or just easy ng-model. so .. want It to be a normal form

Comment: It is a normal form. inputs that use ngModel will have their attribute value populated. If you want to get the value of the fields you could use $("#myForm : input").serialize() or $("#myForm : input").serializeArray()

Comment: Ain't there any jQuery-less option? Doesn't angular NgModelController keeps track of the related DOM node?